# View source for Golang packages in LiteIDE

Tags: go, revel, liteide

What's the easiest way to view source code of golang packages in LiteIDE?

for example, when there are code like this:

```
import "github.com/revel/revel"

func init() {
    // Filters is the default set of global filters.
    revel.Filters = []revel.Filter{
        revel.PanicFilter,             // Recover from panics and display an error page instead.
        revel.RouterFilter,            // Use the routing table to select the right Action
        revel.FilterConfiguringFilter, // A hook for adding or removing per-Action filters.
        revel.ParamsFilter,            // Parse parameters into Controller.Params.
        revel.SessionFilter,           // Restore and write the session cookie.
        revel.FlashFilter,             // Restore and write the flash cookie.
        revel.ValidationFilter,        // Restore kept validation errors and save new ones from cookie.
        revel.I18nFilter,              // Resolve the requested language
        HeaderFilter,                  // Add some security based headers
        revel.InterceptorFilter,       // Run interceptors around the action.
        revel.CompressFilter,          // Compress the result.
        revel.ActionInvoker,           // Invoke the action.
    }
}
```

If I want to know what's the revel.PanicFilter really do, I would visit the http://github.com/revel/revel and seek the source code..

When using C++ (QtCreator), i would only need to ctrl+click then it would visit the declaration/implementation.

My `Jump to declaration` menu doesn't work in LiteIDE, maybe because the packages are compressed in `.a` archive?

```
file pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/revel/revel.a 
pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/revel/revel.a: current ar archive
```

Is there an easier way to go to declaration to view the source just like in QtCreator?

Comment: It looks like LiteIDE is looking in the wrong spot for the package sources. You should be looking in `$GOPATH/src` and not `$GOPATH/pkg/linux_amd64`. I'm not sure if there is a LiteIDE configuration option to change that.

Comment: It's a bug in the current version.

Comment: well, I'll use grep/ag, then open the file for now

Comment: now I'm using https://github.com/b3log/wide it's the only IDE AFAIK that have working `godef` integration

Comment: `SublimeText 3` also works XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**F2** key jumps to the declaration of library function in **Lite IDE v24.3**

Comment: Yeah, it works now on `LiteIDE 26`, using `Ctrl+Shift+J` instead of `F2`

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+Shift+J works for me on LiteIDE 26. F2 doesnt work!